# Service user gets access denied for share, while NTFS and share permissions are given

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-services

Please help - can't seem to wrap my head around this:

All Windows environment. Application needs to write data in a network share. The application in question is located on srv01, thus the service was set to logon with a AD service user "service-worker". It was given OS permissions "Log on as service", "Log on as Batch" and permissions to the application files it needs and service starts and works just fine. It can write to UNC shares on srv01.

However, the application reports "access denied" when trying to write to share \srv02\dir. For \srv02\dir, I've given the "service-worker" full control permissions:
[share permissions for service-worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJKTp.png)
and NTFS-permission wise change and read permissions to \srv02\dir\subdir.

Now to debug I tried to reproduce the error with Powershell

```
$username = 'service-worker'
$password = 'somePassword'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePassword)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName srv01 -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    "Hello World" | Out-File -FilePath "\\srv02\dir\subdir\test1.txt"    
}
```

Which gives me

```
PS H:\> C:\Users\myUser\Scripts\CreateUNCFileAsUser.ps1
Access to the path '\\srv02\dir\subdir\test1.txt' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
    + PSComputerName        : srv02
```

On srv02, the effective permissions for the directory and user looks like this:
[results from advanced security "effective permission"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0uDJ.png)

What am I missing? The user can't read on srv02 either. Added it to the same permissions group for NTFS as me (which is "full control" on the whole server) - same error. Then tried to write to share root \srv02\dir\test1.txt - same error. Tried to invoke the command from srv02 and it says it doesn't have permissions to log on, which is as it should be and fine by me.

Edit: On srv01 when using powershell (as Invoke-Command might not allow more than one hop) I get the same error as above, only difference PSComputername being "srv01".

Comment: Are you able to RDP onto srv01 > run powershell *as* the service-worker user > read files from \\srv02\dir? Powershell remote sessions (via `Invoke-Command`) are not allowed to make the second hop from local -> srv01 -> srv02 by default: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop

Comment: How does the Application attempt to read files? For example, a "service" does not log in interactively, so that process cannot use network drive letter mappings or run login scripts etc. You can test the account's share/ntfs access by mapping a drive from somewhere else like `net use x: \\srv02\dir /USER:domain\username` and see if you can browse

Comment: Thx for your help. On srv01 via RDP => Powershell I get:

Access to the path '\\srv01\dir\subdir\test1.txt' is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
    + PSComputerName        : srv01

The application is a ERP system that I believe is written in C++. At the end of the day, I think it to issue ordinary Windows API calls.
The application was given the path to write to in UNC, no network drive letter mappings involved.

Comment: Is your account granted the "network logon" right to srv02?

Comment: By "network logon" you mean "Access this computer from the network"? It is on srv02 (among others) set to "Everyone" and "Authenticated users" which should cover "service-worker"

Comment: Alas, when i put net use x: \\srv02\dir /user:DOMAIN\service-worker => result:
The command completed successfully.
I can see the files in \\..\subdir and can write via explorer.exe